# Convergence of $a_n=\sum\limits_{m=2}^{n} \frac{(-1)^mm}{(\ln(m))^m}$ and $b_n = \sum\limits_{m=2}^{n} \frac{1}{(\ln(m))^m}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, limits-without-lhopital, limsup-and-liminf

> Let $a_1=b_1=0$ and for each $n\geq 2$, let $a_n$ and $b_n$ be real
>   numbers given by
>   $a_n=\sum\limits_{m=2}^{n}  \frac{(-1)^mm}{(\ln(m))^m}$ and $b_n =
>  \sum\limits_{m=2}^{n} \frac{1}{(\ln(m))^m}$,  then what can be said about the
>   convergence of sequences $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$?

If I am not wrong, is the question only asking whether the series

$\sum\limits_{m=2}^{\infty}  \frac{(-1)^mm}{(\ln(m))^m}$ and $ \sum\limits_{m=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(\ln(m))^m}$ converge or diverge?

In which case they both converge by root test. What is the correct response to this?

Comment: that is the correct response to this if nothing more is asked

Comment: $a_n$ : Leibniz convergence criterion ; $b_n$ : ratio test

Answer (score 1):

Using [Cauchy's n-th root tes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test)t $a_n$ converges absolutely. Similarly $b_n$ converges using $n-th root test.